# Why is * sometimes not interpreted as regex in my scenario

Tags: bash

I don't understand why the first command below works, and when i use the expr command it required * to be escaped. In my opinion, the * should always have to be escaped since it's part of BRE, and therefore should be escaped as to not represent "any".  So I don't get why the first command is actually working.

```
$  a=2; b=3; echo $((a*b))
6
$ var1=$(expr 2 * 3) ; echo $var1
expr: syntax error: unexpected argument ‘Desktop’
$ var1=$(expr 2 \* 3) ; echo $var1
6
```

Comment: 'expr' is a program used in ancient shell code to do math. In Posix shells like bash, use $(( expression )). In bash, ksh88+, mksh/pdksh, or zsh, you can also use '(( expression ))' or 'let expression'.

Comment: This has no relevance to my question sorry.

Comment: It's not regex but math...

Comment: The `$(  )` syntax runs the enclosed command, and expands the args. The * expands to a list of filenames, of which the `Desktop` directory happens to be the first, and `expr` does not accept. Incidentally, this is "shell globbing", which is different to BRE. The $(( )) syntax is a shell arithmetic substitution, and the enclosed text has different syntax rules that permit variables (without $var expansion), integers and operators.

Comment: To clarify it has never been interpreted as regex, that would be .*
This is shell globbing

Comment: Thanks Paul_Pedant, that helps.  So I think I have it now.  I was unaware that the syntax of bash interpretation is modified during arithmatic in cases where it's the operator used exclusively between numbers in the (()) expression.  That is the key thing I didn't know, and now it makes sense.

Comment: @johnsmith Shell syntax is extremely context-dependent, and glob expansion is no exception. There are a number of contexts where globs are not expanded, including any arithmetic context (like inside `$(( ))`, `(( ))`, or a (non-associative) array index), the right side of a simple assignment (e.g. `var=*.txt`), the subject of a `case` statement (e.g. `case *.txt in ...`), inside a `[[ ]]` conditional expression (except the right side of a `=` or `==` comparison) (but globs *will* be expanded to filenames inside a `[ ]` test expression), and probably others I'm not thinking of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion)

> The expression undergoes the same expansions as if it were within double quotes

But when using expr(1) you are just passing everything as command line arguments and as such they are subject to all the regular [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) including [Filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) (which uses globbing not regex because I have an obligation to be pedantic).

This is called out in the [expr man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/expr.1.html)

> Beware that many operators need to be escaped or quoted for shells

Comment: And the same applies for `[` / `test`.
Paranoia quotes are your friend with both.

Comment: So off that link it states "if both arguments are numbers" something something something. So what I'm seeing is if it's numbers between the (()), then the operator for the comparison is treated as arithmatic.  Is that correct?

Comment: @johnsmith I think you're reading that from the expr man page and not the manual on arithmetic expansion.

Comment: Yes that's the last link you referenced, so I checked that.  Is that not right?  The arithmetic exapnsion link's first paragraph is just a riddle to understand, so I gave up and went to the next link.

Comment: Ok right, I made more effort trying to understand the arithmetic link.  So double quotes preserves the literal characters, and since the expression undergoes the same expansion as if it were double quoted, then by recursion, it means the original * (in my scenario) was preserved, thus leaving the the resulting values to be interpreted by the defined operators in the link below.  Right I think I finally get it.
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic

Comment: @johnsmith yes that is correct but arithmetic expansion and expr are two different things so the sentence about numbers being treated as arithmetic else lexicographical doesn't apply to shell arithmetic expansion

Comment: I don't understand what your telling me now, I am completely lost with your last comment.

Comment: The short is anything in `$()` is a literal command-line command and expr is just another program (or shell built-in that behaves like one) on the system.  Since an unquoted `*` is substituted for all nearby files on other shell commands it is here.  Anything inside `$(())` is a math expression and is parsed by the shell itself directly with special syntax where you don't expect to want a list of files.